# how accessing lowest level child node in xml via DOM

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have xml level nodes like:

```
<matrix1>
  <row1>
    <column>679</column>
    <column>9</column>
  </row2>
  <row2>
    <column>78</column>
    <column>29</column>
  </row2>
<matrix1>
```

i seen here lot of similar things,but not exactly more level child nodes like this,
May i can in DOM after parsing process, skip parent nodes a access direct to `<column>679</column>`?  or iterate each level to lowest child to getting numerical value?
thanks for yours time to help.

Answer (score 0):

An [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) expression is probably what you need here. You can selects column nodes in the document no matter where they are using this pattern:

```
//column
```

Here is a working snippet:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse(____your XML InputStream____);
XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//column");
NodeList nl = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Check the [Java XPath API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html) to get more information.

You should also check the syntax of your XML input. The matrix1 and row1 have no end tag, here is the corrected XML:

```
<matrix1>
    <row1>
        <column>679</column>
        <column>9</column>
    </row1>
    <row2>
        <column>78</column>
        <column>29</column>
    </row2>
</matrix1>
```

Comment: very thanks to you, few minutes ago i write a DOM scaffold for this xml,but i have some doubts that not will not work, and when its happend, i try this XPath, and last question: can then parsing number in columns tags to integer like a:  int a = Integer.parseInt ...?

Comment: Yes you can, iterate over the NodeList and get the first child text (-> node.getFirstChild().getTextContent())